# How to join AX tables using .net interop?

Tags: .net, axapta, x++, proxy-classes, dynamics-ax-2012

I am trying to create a utility for AX 2012 in visual studio using .net interop to X++ and proxy classes, I've added necessary tables in my project, I can access tables individually and can loop them through .next() method, but I want to join these tables so I can get my desired results (I want to display a grid with item id, name alias, color, size information).

I am unable to figure out how to join `InventTable`, `InventDim and`InventDimCombination` for this purpose. Can you guys please tell me how can I join AOT tables without having to use traditional .net business connector methods in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to AX 2012 R2. Then use [LINQ](http://kamalblogs.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/programming-improvements-with-dynamics-ax-2012-r2/). A [code example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj677293.aspx).

**Update:**

If not possible, then create an AX query, either in AX or programmaticly from .Net. Then use the query the get the AX records. A [working example](http://community.dynamics.com/product/ax/axtechnical/b/daxmusings/archive/2011/05/05/ax-2012-amp-net-coding-business-logic-in-c.aspx).

Or use the [AX 2012 AIF Query AIF Web Service](http://ax2012aifintegration.blogspot.dk/2012/05/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-application_14.html).

Comment: thanks Jan for replying, currently it is not possible for us to upgrade to R2, is there any other way to accomplish it ? there has to be a way for such a basic operation, if we can access tables in VS why cant we join them ?